# Draw tick lines at the top of highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to also draw tick lines along the top of the chart using highcharts for the x-axis? I have seen the opposite attribute:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite

But this inverts the x-axis ticks and labels. I simply wanted to also include some tick marks along the top for the x-axis as well. This is very typical in scientific plots.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding an additional opposite x-axis linked to the main one with disabled labels:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: [{}, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    opposite: true,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }],
  series: [{
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b9o4krjc/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.linkedTo